# Nhibernate QueryOver does not work but CreateSqlQuery works

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In my project I have a class named User with the following definition:

```
public class User
    {
        public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is mapper class:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.UserId).Column("UserId");
            Map(x => x.UserName).Column("UserName");
            Map(x => x.Password).Column("Password");
        }
    }
```

when I try to execute the following code it does not return any result:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetByUserPassword(string userName, string password)
        {
            var result = Session.QueryOver<User>()
                .Where(x => x.Password == password && x.UserName == userName)
                .List<User>();
            return result.AsQueryable();
        }
```

But when I use CreateSqlQuery("select * from [dbo].[User]") method it returns value without column names:

[image: result without column names]

and here is my Nhibernate configuration code:

```
public class NHibernateSessionFactory
    {
        private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

        private readonly string ConnectionString = "";       

        public NHibernateSessionFactory(String connectionString)
        {
            this.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        }

        public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get { return sessionFactory ?? (sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory()); }
        }

        public ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            try
            {
                return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey(ConnectionString)))
               .Mappings(m =>
                         m.FluentMappings
                             .AddFromAssemblyOf<User>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }


        }
    }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: In your screenshot of the immediate window, it looks like an exception occurred, possibly when running the QueryOver query. Is this the case? If so, could you post information about the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use QueryOver, use just Query:

```
var result = Session.Query<User>()
            .Where(x => x.Password == password && x.UserName == userName);
//already IQueryable<User>
```

This was helpful but my mistake was a mistake in adding MapClass Assembly which was in other assembly:

.AddFromAssemblyOf()

Comment: Only one possible explanation: the User class is not mapped. Your UserMap is not being loaded.

Comment: Maybe, but as you see my CreateSessionFactory method seems to be correct!

Comment: Please see if the UserMap runs, by adding a breakpoint. It is a known issue that NHibernate does not complain when executing queries over unmapped classes. Do share your findings here, please!

Comment: My mapCode class was in another assembly, when I changed it everything worked! thanks alot